# Как удалить записи, содержащие определенные буквы?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Мне нужно удалить все строки, записи которых начинаются с `ААА` в определенном столбце.

Пример входных данных:

```
|Column|Column_1|           Time|
_________________________________
AAA_1  |12      |12.01.20 10:00:00
__________________________________
888_1  |zab_1   |12.01.20 11:00:00
__________________________________
BBB_1  |zab_1   |12.01.20 10:00:00
```

То, что желаю получить:

```
|Column|Column_1|           Time|
_________________________________
BBB    |zab_1   |12.01.20
```

Comment: Ваш код не совсем соответствует описанию. Можете привести в вопросе небольшой пример данных и результат, который вы хотите получить?

Comment: @MaxU готово, можете посмотреть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
  Column Column_1               Time
0  AAA_1       12  12.01.20 10:00:00
1  888_1    zab_1  12.01.20 11:00:00
2  BBB_1    zab_1  12.01.20 10:00:00

In [9]: res = df.loc[~df["Column"].str.contains(r"^(?:AAA|\d{3})")]
```

результат:

```
In [10]: res
Out[10]: 
  Column Column_1               Time
2  BBB_1    zab_1  12.01.20 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = df[~df.Column.str.startswith("AAA")]
```

---

Тест:

```
>>> df
```

> ```
>   Column Column_1               Time
> 0  AAA_1       12  12.01.20 10:00:00
> 1  888_1    zab_1  12.01.20 11:00:00
> 2  BBB_1    zab_1  12.01.20 10:00:00
> ```

```
>>> df[~df.Column.str.startswith("AAA")]
```

> ```
>  Column Column_1               Time
> 1  888_1    zab_1  12.01.20 11:00:00
> 2  BBB_1    zab_1  12.01.20 10:00:00
> ```